# Source control binding invalid, tried changing source control to no avail

Tags: binding, version-control, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I got my project from TFS but for some reason the second time I tried to open it, it said that my bindings were invalid. I haven't changed any file names. I looked up the issue and tried to undo and redo the bindings by going to source **control > advanced > change source control**, but after I unbind my solution, when I click 'bind' it just immediately says it's invalid again.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to suggest this, but I would start from deleting the workspace and download solution from source control again. If this does not work, can you post your workspace mappings and solution structure - does it include websites?